# io.swagger.v3.parser.OpenAPIV3Parser is not exported

Tags: java, maven, swagger, openapi

I am trying to parse OPEN API V3 document using swagger-parser-v3 (https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-parser) 2.0.29 library. But when I compile the code I get the following error.

```
[ERROR] io.swagger.v3.oas.models.servers.Server is not exported
[ERROR] io.swagger.v3.oas.models.OpenAPI is not exported
[ERROR] io.swagger.v3.oas.models.PathItem is not exported
[ERROR] io.swagger.v3.oas.models.Operation is not exported
[ERROR] io.swagger.v3.oas.models.Paths is not exported
[ERROR] io.swagger.v3.parser.OpenAPIV3Parser is not exported
```

Here is my code

```
import io.swagger.v3.parser.OpenAPIV3Parser;
OpenAPI openAPI = new OpenAPIV3Parser().read(swaggerFilePath);
```

I am seeing this issue while building using maven.
Can someone please help to address this issue.